# Granting permissions to library, and sharing everything with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

[image]

Is it possible to achieve the same sharing setting with PowerShell, as you would for sharing a document library? Also without foreaching every single item in a document library. After my understanding you can share the document library with Set-PnPListPermission and the items with Set-PnPListItemPermission, I would hope to only share with the list so I won't need to loop trough every single list items.
Anyone know how I can achieve this?